# styles being used from non active stylesheet

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, styles

I have a created a layout called admin that relies on certain css to render my design.  In one of my controls I am not using this layout, but for some reason some of the styles ('body' for example) seems to be pulling from a css that I only have attached to my admin layout.  Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

What stylesheet includes do you have on your layout?  If you have a tag like this:

```
stylesheet_link_tag :all
```

Then it will include all styles in the stylesheets directory.   Just a guess but this could be the reason.

For More Reference see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/StylesheetTagHelpers.html)